# Login logout below menu bar

Tags: filters, login

I would like to display a Login / logout link above menu as my theme doesn't have this feature.

Login/Register at right top corner and same it should show in mobile version as well.

I am using subscribe pro theme by HAPPYTHEMES. You can check the demo version here: https://www.happythemes.com/demo/?theme=subscribe-pro

Comment: Create the child theme and use [wp_loginout()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_loginout) function in the corresponding place.

Answer (score 0):

If your theme adheres to WordPress standards the menu is generated with a call to [`wp_nav_menu`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/). This function has a filter that allows you to modify the html. Like this:

```
add_filter ('wp_nav_menu', 'wpse312466_add_loginlink'); 
function wpse312466_add_loginlink ($nav_menu, $args) {
  $nav_menu = '<div id="loglink"><a href="/link/to/loginpage">Login here</a></div>' . $nav_link
  return $nav_menu
  }
```

Now it depends on your css skills to get that link in the place where you want it to be.

The obvious place to stick this code is in a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes), but you could also make it [into a plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin).